# How to draw image and text in Image Context?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I tried to draw text on the image.When I don't apply the transformations, then the image is drawn at the bottom left corner and the image and text are fine(Fig 2),but I want the image on the top left of the view.

Below is my drawRect implementation.

How to flip the image so that text and image are aligned properly?

or

How to move the image to the top left of the view?

If I don't use the following function calls image gets created at the bottom of the view.(Fig 2)

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0); 




 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {

         UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);

         // Fig 2 comment these lines to have Fig 2
         CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, self.bounds.size.height);
         CGContextScaleCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, -1.0);
        // Fig 2 Applying the above transformations results in Fig 1

         UIImage *natureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Nature"];
         CGRect natureImageRect = CGRectMake(130, 380, 50, 50);
         [natureImage drawInRect:natureImageRect];


         UIFont *numberFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:28.0];
         NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
         NSString * aNumber = @"111";
        [aNumber drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 335) withFont:numberFont];    

        UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
        NSString * aText = @"Hello";
        [aText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(220, 370) withFont: textFont];
        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image);
        NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
        NSLog(@"filePath :%@", filePath);

        BOOL isFileCreated = [fm createFileAtPath:filePath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

        if(isFileCreated)
        {
            NSLog(@"File created at Path %@",filePath);
        }

    }
```

[image: Flipped image when translation is applied]

[image: Image at the bottom left corner without translation]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to draw the same image (except I did not use the nature image). Its not in a draw rect but depending on your end goal it might be better to do this outside of the draw rect in a custom method and set the self.image to the result of -(UIImage *)imageToDraw. It outputs this:

[image: You can tweak the frames to align stuff]

Here is the code:

```
- (UIImage *)imageToDraw
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(320, 480), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    UIImage *natureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage.png"];
    [natureImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(130, 380, 50, 50)];

    UIFont *numberFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:28.0];
    NSString * aNumber = @"111";
    [aNumber drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 335) withFont:numberFont];

    UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
    NSString * aText = @"Hello";
    [aText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(220, 370) withFont:textFont];

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}

- (NSString *)filePath
{
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
}

- (void)testImageWrite
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self imageToDraw]);
    NSError *writeError = nil;
    BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:[self filePath] options:0 error:&writeError];
    if (!success || writeError != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Writing: %@",writeError.description);
    }
}
```

anyway - hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your image frame of reference is the standard iOS frame of reference: the origin is at the top left corner. Instead the text you are drawing with Core Text has the old frame of reference, with the origin at the bottom left corner. Just apply a transform on the text (not the graphics context) like so:

```
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f));
```

then all your stuff will be layout as if the axis origin were in the top left corner.

If you have to write entire sentences with Core Text as opposed to just words take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2011/08/quick-tip-drawing-core-text-right-side-up/)

Comment: How to apply CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f)); only for text?

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that drawRect method is for drawing in a view not to create an image. Performance issue, drawInRect is called a lot.With this intention is better viewDidLoad or some custom method.

I have done an example with your request:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGFloat margin = 10;

CGFloat y = self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5;
CGFloat x = margin;
UIImage *natureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];

CGRect natureImageRect = CGRectMake(x, y - 20, 40, 40);
[natureImage drawInRect:natureImageRect];
x += 40 + margin;

UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
NSString * aText = @"Hello";

NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
style.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
NSDictionary *attr = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style,
                       NSFontAttributeName: textFont};

CGSize size = [aText sizeWithAttributes:attr];
[aText drawInRect: CGRectMake(x, y - size.height * 0.5, 100, 40)
         withFont: textFont
    lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeClip
        alignment: UITextAlignmentLeft];

self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.imageView.image = self.image;

}
```

[image]